# Forming an ANOVA table without observed values (regression analysis)

Tags: regression, self-study, anova

[image: Regression Analysis]

Need some help in forming the ANOVA table without observed values. 
I only managed to find SST with the first line of hint, but do not know how to proceed to find SSTreatment or SSError. 
Any hint/solution will be greatly appreciated.